# Optimization and error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'generator' and 'generator'"

Tags: python, function, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to do (from a math point of view), what is described in the following image (for presentation purpose) :

[image]

In my code , i took mock values for the experimental and initial guess vector. How could i manage to **fit my b parameter** , at each experimental time , **so that Vn = En** ? (Thus requiring to **update each time the 10 solutions for each new b value**).

I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible to give a MRE below , if you need any additional information for clarification purposes, just let me  know :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


"Mock experimental vector"


time = np.array([0,0.1,1,3,10])
E = np.array([1000,555.5,100.3,52,31])


"Mock initial guess for b"

bini = np.array([1000,800,600,400,200])


def function(b):
    x=np.arange(0,50,1)
    wbis=np.array(x)
    def f(x):
         return x*(np.sin(x)/np.cos(x))-b
    def fprime(x):
        return np.tan(x)+ x*(1/np.cos(x))**2
    def fprime2(x):
        return 2*1/(np.cos(x)**2)*(x*np.tan(x)+1)
    w=[] 
    for b in bini :
        roots = newton(f,x0=[x],fprime=fprime,fprime2=fprime2)
        roots = np.around(roots, decimals=3,)
        a = roots[roots >= 0]
        g = np.unique(a)
        g=g[:10]
        w.append(g)
    def v(y,z):
        return np.exp(y)*(np.sum(np.cos(z)))
    V=[]
    for t,g in zip(time,w):
            q=(v(t,g))
            V.append(q)
    for h,m in zip(V,E):
        return (h-m)**2


rep=minimize(function,bini)
```

I get the following traceback :

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'generator' and 'generator'
```

I am quite new to python, and might not have chosen the best solver for my problem. I'd gladly appreciate any help and clues as to what to change in my code.

**Edit :**

To answer one comment about how my B parameter affect the value of V .
If the code is written this way :

```
for b in bini:
    w=np.arange(0,50,1)
    wbis=np.array(w)
    s=[]
    def f(x):
        return x*(np.sin(x)/np.cos(x))-b
    def fprime(x):
        return np.tan(x)+ x*(1/np.cos(x))**2
    def fprime2(x):
        return 2*1/(np.cos(x)**2)*(x*np.tan(x)+1) 
    roots = newton(f,x0=[w],fprime=fprime,fprime2=fprime2)
    roots = np.around(roots, decimals=3,)
    a = roots[roots > 0]
    g = np.unique(a)
    g=g[:5]
    s.append(g)
    print(s)
    def v(y,z):
        return np.exp(y)*(np.sum(np.cos(z)))
    V=[]
    for t,g in zip(time,s):
            q=(v(t,g))
            V.append(q)
    print(V)
    def fun(b):
        for h,m in zip(V,E):
            return (h-m)**2
```

Returns the following values (limited at 5 solutions for visibility purpose) :

```
[array([ 1.569,  4.708,  7.846, 10.985, 14.123])]
[0.008981285528509656] "value of V at t = 0 and b = 1000"
[array([ 1.569,  4.707,  7.844, 10.982, 14.12 ])]
[0.009981067026682361]  "value of V at t = 0.1 and b = 800 and so on"
[array([ 1.568,  4.705,  7.841, 10.977, 14.114])]
[0.01298032871327624]
[array([ 1.567,  4.701,  7.834, 10.968, 14.102])]
[0.01997678747959065]
[array([ 1.563,  4.689,  7.815, 10.941, 14.067])]
[0.03894333935236951]
```

Comment: can you tell us at which line the error happen?

Comment: The error happens at the last line  (rep=minimize(function,bini))

Comment: are you sure because the error message (if you shown the right one said that there is a "-" operator on the said line so it cannot be this one. you should add the whole traceback rather than the error description only

Comment: There are some oddities with this function.  I don't see why you'd need the line `yield(q)`, and the final loop will only return the first value: you probably want to sum all of the values instead.  Most significantly, however, your function returns the same value regardless of what value the parameter `b` takes, so optimizing it won't achieve anything. I really can't tell from your question how you are expecting to involve the value of `b` in your calculations, so this is a math problem, not a Python problem.

Comment: Thank you both, @Luke Woodward, you were right. The `yield(q)` caused problems. I edited my question to show how b parameter should influence my function. I don't know why when it is inside the `def function(b)` , it does not work anymore (now my optimisation "works" but nothing happens as bini is not modified).

Comment: Apologies, I missed seeing the `b` in the definition of `f(x)`.  However, my point about your function returning the same value regardless of the input value of `b` still stands.  What kind of value is `b` supposed to contain, a scalar or a vector value?  It's passed in as a vector value, but before your code gets the chance to use this vector value, you replace it with a scalar value from `bini`.  Note that `bini` won't get modified: instead, the result of the optimization will be returned as a new array.

Comment: `b` is a scalar value.  You're right, when i printed the `minimize(function,bini)` I got the same array as bini. And I don't know why it works (taking into account the different values possible for b) outside the function (after the edit) , but not inside the function.